# R: dplyr group_by . looping through each group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm currently dealing with a set of time series data. The data frame has 4 columns (dates,value,month, and size). The month column just indicates which month the date is in.  I want to be able to record at the first instance within the first three days of each month such that the value is over 0.5 and the next time (two days before the end of the month) the value reverts back to negative number within each month.

for example:

```
Dates      Value
01/01/2016  0.360588739
01/02/2016  0.595765265  ***
01/03/2016  0.448855962
01/04/2016  0.295765265
01/05/2016  -0.24470058   ***
01/06/2016  -0.169958947
01/07/2016  -0.216953024
01/08/2016  -0.287801531
01/09/2016  -0.328458361
01/10/2016  -0.468009532
01/11/2016  -0.368107924
01/12/2016  -0.500611564
01/13/2016  -0.506701117
01/14/2016  -0.564366906
01/15/2016  -0.737858078  
01/16/2016  -0.764897486
```

And If the first time value>0.5 happens after the first three days just ignore and move on to next month.
If the value never goes back to be negative before 2 days prior to the end of the months, just record the last value

the operation done for each month is a bit complicated so I thought a for loop is unavoidable. any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned that. Either two lists of dates(the date of first time over 0.5, the date of reversion back to negative) or a list of difference in "size" of the first instance and the second instance in each month.

Comment: @casualprogrammer: what is the `size` column? Can you give some data or can we just assume some integers.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to get the first result you want is to use `dplyr` with custom functions:

1. `first.over`: to detect if there is a `Value > 0.5` within the first three days of a month.
2. `reversion`: to detect the next date (after the date detected by `first.over`, if it exists) that is more than two days before the end of the month for which the `Value` reverts to a negative number.

The data cleaning chain is `group_by` the `Month`:

1. Use `mutate` with the `first.over` function by `Month` to create a new column `over_0.5` of the date within the first three days of the month for which `Value` exceeds `0.5`. `first.over` will return `NA` (and `over_0.5` will be `NA`s) if this date is not detected. Note that `first.over` is used as a `windowing` function so that `over_0.5` will be a vector of the same value (date) returned by the logic within `first.over`. This is in order to preserve the data in the `Value` column when we call `reversion` later.
2. Use `filter` to remove those months for which `over_0.5` is `NA`. This accomplishes what you want in terms of ignoring these months.
3. Use `summarise` to summarize the result.

   - Summarize the `over_0.5` column by simply picking the `first` value recalling that this column has the same value by `Month`.
   - Use the `reversion` function to compute the `reversion_date` by `Month`.

The code is as follows:

```
first.over <- function(v, d) {
  # get index to first date for which the Value > 0.5
  # this will be NA if there is no date where Value > 0.5
  i <- first(which(v > 0.5))
  # if that date is in the first three days, return the date
  # otherwise return NA
  if (!is.na(i) && i < 4) {
    return(d[i])
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

reversion <- function(v,fo,d) {
  # if there is no first over 0.5 date, return NA
  if (any(is.na(fo)) || length(fo) == 0) return (NA)
  # get indices i for all negative Values
  i <- which(v < 0.0)
  # get the first index j from i for which the date[i]
  # is greater than the first over 0.5 date. Again, 
  # this will be NA if there are no negative Values
  # or if there are no dates with negative values that 
  # are greater than the first over 0.5 date.
  j <- i[first(which(d[i] > fo[1]))]
  # if that date is two or more days before the last day 
  # of the month, return that date; otherwise, return 
  # the last day.
  if (!is.na(j) && j < (length(v) - 1)) {
    return(d[j])
  } else {
    return(d[length(v)])
  }
}

result <- df %>% group_by(Month) 
             %>% mutate(over_0.5 = first.over(Value,Dates))
             %>% filter(!is.na(over_0.5))
             %>% summarise(first(over_0.5),reversion_date = reversion(Value,over_0.5,Dates))
```

This code only generate the first type of output you requested. To generate the other, you need to define the data for the `Size` column.

Notes:

1. Both `first.over` and `reversion` operate under the assumption that the `Dates` column is sorted by the date (in ascending order) as in a time series.
2. Moreover, `first.over` assumes that there is a row for each date. However, the logic can be easily modified in case there are missing data (rows) for days of the month by comparing the day in the date instead of the row index `i`.
3. Although `reversion` can handle missing data for days of the month, data for the last day of the month must be present to meet your requirements. Otherwise, `reversion` will return the last `Date` for the `Month`.

Results using the data you posted (augmented with a `Month` column per your specification) is as follows:

```
print(result)
### A tibble: 3 x 3
##  Month first(over_0.5) reversion_date
##  <int>          <date>         <date>
##1     1      2016-01-02     2016-01-05
```

Using a larger dataset (still far from a complete test):

```
df <- structure(list(Dates = structure(c(16801, 16802, 16803, 16804, 
16805, 16806, 16807, 16808, 16809, 16810, 16811, 16812, 16813, 
16814, 16815, 16816, 16831, 16832, 16833, 16834, 16835, 16860, 
16861, 16862, 16863, 16864, 16865, 16866, 16867, 16868, 16869, 
16870, 16871, 16872, 16873, 16874, 16875, 16876, 16877, 16878, 
16879, 16880, 16881, 16882, 16883, 16884, 16885, 16886, 16887, 
16888, 16889, 16890, 16891, 16892, 16893, 16894, 16895, 16921, 
16922, 16923, 16924, 16925, 16951, 16952), class = "Date"), Value = c(0.360588739, 
0.595765265, 0.448855962, 0.295765265, -0.24470058, -0.169958947, 
-0.216953024, -0.287801531, -0.328458361, -0.468009532, -0.368107924, 
-0.500611564, -0.506701117, -0.564366906, -0.737858078, -0.764897486, 
-0.864897486, -0.764897486, -0.764897486, -0.764897486, -0.764897486, 
-0.764897486, -0.360588739, -0.460588739, 0.564897486, 0.664897486, 
0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 
0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 
0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 
0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 
0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, 0.664897486, -0.664897486, 
-0.664897486, -0.664897486, 0.764897486, 0.764897486, 0.764897486, 
0.764897486, 0.764897486, 0.264897486, 0.264897486, 0.264897486, 
0.264897486, -0.264897486, -0.264897486), Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), .Names = c("Dates", 
"Value", "Month"), row.names = c(NA, -64L), class = "data.frame")
```

The results are:

```
print(result)
### A tibble: 3 x 3
##  Month first(over_0.5) reversion_date
##  <int>          <date>         <date>
##1     1      2016-01-02     2016-01-05
##2     3      2016-03-03     2016-03-29
##3     4      2016-04-01     2016-04-30
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! that was very helpful